# Не могу программно удалённо подключиться к виртуалке

Tags: python

Юзаю для подключения winrm следующим образом -

```
import winrm

sess = winrm.Session('192.168.0.3', auth=('Orizis', '6699'))
result = sess.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])
```

И мне выдаёт ошибку -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\winrm\transport.py", line 340, in _send_message_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error:  for url: http://192.168.0.3:5985/wsman

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 85, in <module>
    result = sess.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\winrm\__init__.py", line 39, in run_cmd
    shell_id = self.protocol.open_shell()
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\winrm\protocol.py", line 166, in open_shell
    res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\winrm\protocol.py", line 243, in send_message
    resp = self.transport.send_message(message)
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\winrm\transport.py", line 334, in send_message
    response = self._send_message_request(prepared_request, message)
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\winrm\transport.py", line 344, in _send_message_request
    raise InvalidCredentialsError("the specified credentials were rejected by the server")
winrm.exceptions.InvalidCredentialsError: the specified credentials were rejected by the server
```

Все данные вводятся правильно, настройки виртуалки Win 7 -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка после нескольких предложенных правок в виртуалке -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0476F730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.0.3', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0476F730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 85, in <module>
    result = sess.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\winrm\__init__.py", line 39, in run_cmd
    shell_id = self.protocol.open_shell()
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\winrm\protocol.py", line 166, in open_shell
    res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\winrm\protocol.py", line 243, in send_message
    resp = self.transport.send_message(message)
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\winrm\transport.py", line 334, in send_message
    response = self._send_message_request(prepared_request, message)
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\winrm\transport.py", line 339, in _send_message_request
    response = self.session.send(prepared_request, timeout=self.read_timeout_sec)
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\OverNiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.0.3', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0476F730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера'))
```

Comment: Вы вроде с авторизацией подключаетесь, а на скрине стоит "Нет авторизации". И порт другой.

Comment: Ну допустим изменил порт и поставил метод аутентификации на внешняя, также менял на Гостевая ОС, ошибка изменилась и стала больше

Comment: Докинул новую ошибку